# Android Studio Java Threads

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I read about threads in Android Studio and I wanted to ask some questions. Are threads a must have in my application to avoid lag or only when you make really big and consuming apps? I am asking this because I have little lag on my app and I wanted to know if it is because I didn't use threads. I don't think it is because of useless stuff I did, I was pretty vigilant with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Threads are a vital component of building any large scale application. For example lets say you have a line of code that performs some unit of work which requires some time to be finished for example

```
...
// takes 500ms to complete could be a network operation/could be accessing camera, 
// initializing recorder etc. (Initalizing recorder takes 100ms most of the time)
   doSomeTimeIntensiveTask(); 
...
```

In such cases you would need to perform this task on a different thread and not on your UI/MAIN thread because for a end user using the application, IF you were to perform this on the UI/MAIN thread then he/she would notice the time delay as a stutter/lag kind of experience which makes for a bad UI experience in general.

Additionally there are tasks like making a HTTP request that require an in-determinate amount of time to actually finish in such cases, if such tasks was performed on the UI/MAIN thread then the application would be STUCK until the task was completed which sometimes causes the android OS to show pop up messages like `the application doesn't seem to be responding do you want to force close the app?` or some similar message, which again is bad user experience.

So in your case, I would try to identify exactly which piece of code is causing the lag in my UI/MAIN thread and put that part of the code in a separate thread and write a callback to continue executing correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Without more information, it is impossible for anyone to answer this question in any reasonable manner.

Generally speaking, though, the main reasons to create additional threads (beyond the ones already used in the framework), is if you are doing heavy operations such as I/O (heavy read/write or http), graphics, or really complex calculations.

Look into [Processes and Threads](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/processes-and-threads.html) and [AsyncTask](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

To briefly quote the most relevant portion to this question:

> When your app performs intensive work in response to user interaction, this single thread model can yield poor performance unless you implement your application properly. Specifically, if everything is happening in the UI thread, performing long operations such as network access or database queries will block the whole UI. When the thread is blocked, no events can be dispatched, including drawing events. From the user's perspective, the application appears to hang. Even worse, if the UI thread is blocked for more than a few seconds (about 5 seconds currently) the user is presented with the infamous "application not responding" (ANR) dialog. The user might then decide to quit your application and uninstall it if they are unhappy.